# Contstant getting "Blocking call to accept-process-output with quit inhibited!" with flyspell mode

Tags: flyspell

After I installed aspell with Emacs 26.3 and turned on flyspell mode, I constantly get the message:

Blocking call to accept-process-output with quit inhibited!

How to suppress these messages?

Comment: What other subprocesses are running in Emacs; e.g., `mu4e`, something else?  Type `M-x list-processes` when you encounter the problem and see what is active.  People have always told me that other process do not generally interfere with each other, but I have found that some subprocesses do in fact affect `aspell` performance on my system.

Comment: There is only one listed:
ispell          18684   run     --              --           aspell -a -m -B --encoding=utf-8